# Looking for a noun or verb for reaching over a threshold, limit, boundary

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm in need of a word for the object or action that causes a limit to be reached, threshold to be passed, capacity of container to be filled, saturation to be reached etc.

It should imply filling and overflowing of a boundary.

The word could be to describe something physical, emotional, or moral.

Something similar to the "last straw".

Comment: Since you've tagged this as a single-word-request, you should include a sample sentence demonstrating how the word would be used.

Comment: Why doesn't _the last straw_ work?

Comment: "The last/final straw" or "the straw that breaks/broke the camel's back" are the standard phrases for this in English. If you don't like them can you explain what's wrong with them and what you want that they don't have. (Have you tried looking them up in a thesaurus or googling for synonyms?)

Comment: @StuartF Last straw doesn't work because the person saying it doesn't know what camels or straws are.

Answer (score 0):

> ([OALD](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/brink?q=brink)) **brink** noun /brɪŋk/
>
> **​the brink (of something)** If you are on the brink of something, you are almost in a very new, dangerous or exciting situation
> on the brink of collapse/war/death/disaster
>
> - Scientists are on the brink of making a major new discovery.
> - He's pulled the company back from the brink (= he has saved it from disaster).
> - teetering/poised/hovering on the brink
> - animals hovering on the very brink of extinction

- ([Nobel Prize Library: Francois Mauriac. Frederic Mistral. 1971](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Nobel_Prize_Library_Francois_Mauriac_Fre/ajU4AAAAIAAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&bsq=%22on+the+brink%22&dq=%22on+the+brink%22&printsec=frontcover))  On the brink of this appalling emptiness, of this day without Maria, which was to be but the first of many other days without her, he was made aware, at one and the same moment, of his dependence and his solitude.

Comment: If you are *on the brink*, you are still on the safe, if perilous, side. You've not had "the last straw" that puts you *over* a limit or boundary, which is what the OP is asking about.

Comment: @DjinTonic The OP also mentions the reaching of a limit: "action that causes a limit to be reached, …, capacity of container to be filled, saturation to be reached".  Reaching the limit does not involve a change in the result that the process of going towards that limit entails.

Comment: @LPH Yes something like "brinkfiller". A chemistry term would be cool. Catalyst or impetus implies change but doesn't describe "filling".

Comment: @DjinTonic Yes, brink is the location, not the filling or the thing that fills. Is there some science term that is the item that is added? Something that is full is saturated, but what is the "saturator"? Or the exact moment at which gravity collapses into a singularity and becomes a black hole or the final saturator that crosses the threshold.